# Single Laravel application or 2(3?) seperate builds?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My main application is being built with Vue (mydomain.com), I also have a REST API (api.mydomain.com) and then my assets (assets.mydomain.com).

The API is unlikely to be used by other developers, and is only for my convenience when building the spa with Vue. Considering this: would it be better to build a single Laravel application that handles all three subdomains OR have a Laravel application that handles the API, a standalone Vue build for my main application and then serve the assets as a seperate build entirely?

What are the pros/cons for a single build vs three?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Laravel in that context but I sure prefer the more modularized approach of having different builds for different functionality.

I normally use the approach with Node.js where I have both assets and api handled by the backend. (Express app etc) and then separate build fetching the data to render in the spa using React. 
This build benefits scalability since you can easilly maintain, track and debug the code. Obviously it makes it also easier for unit testing. And the performance of the SPA isn't affected by the payload routing in the backend since it runs separately and only interact upon request (REST API in my case).

I hope I provided useful insight.